# Old, Unanswered Questions -- what to do?

Tags: discussion

I have reviewed the other 'unanswered question' questions on meta, but they all deal with *'it's my question'* or *'how do I get this answered'* type issues. This question is actually about how I handle other people's unanswered questions as an active SO user who wants to improve the quality and utility of SO?

While searching for help with a problem I have I ran across this: [JBoss and IntelliJ - Use Jboss Plugin to run and deploy or use Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446532/jboss-and-intellij-use-jboss-plugin-to-run-and-deploy-or-use-maven)

The question is a year old, it has no answers, and little love, although somebody upvoted it at some point. It's not a bad question, so maybe nobody knows the answer. The OP has probably moved on with their life (and they haven't used SO for months), and doesn't seem interested in maintaining their question.

The problem I'm having is that I'm hitting quite a few, old, unanswered questions lately when searching SO. This takes up my time (enough of my time that I'm raising this issue).

Perhaps we should have some way of flagging a question as uninteresting, or does the community think that this isn't important enough? I'm not really suggesting a solution here, I just want some guidance to start with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is some problem with the question that makes them unanswerable, you're welcome to flag/vote to close appropriately.

If you know the answer you're more than welcome to answer the question.

You can vote on the post if you feel like it.  If you feel the question is uninteresting or otherwise not worth the attention of getting answered you can downvote it; that's what downvotes are for.

If you think the question is fine, but either don't know the answer or have no interest in posting an answer, then simply move on; there is nothing for you to do.

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't solve my problem -- which is too much cruft when I'm looking for a solution to a problem. Perhaps we need a way of specifying that I'm only interested in answered questions when searching for a solution to a specific problem?

Comment: @EngineerDollery There's a search criteria for that.

Comment: Is there? I know you're probably busy, but if you could point me at some reference it'd be a huge help?

Comment: @EngineerDollery http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Servy I don't believe this answers original question. What engineer-dollery expects is an option for old unmaintained question. As the case is with these type of questions, there is no way to proceed with a solution since data is lacking to complete whole picture and op is un-interested. Flagging questions as "other" and copy pasting a "too old / unmaintained" text to every such question seems less than optimal use of our time.

Comment: @Servy you seem like you're versed in stackoverflow (employee?) - maybe you can suggest where we can suggest/discuss adding new options to the flag menu? To me it seems like a close flag type is missing

Comment: @tutuDajuju If a question doesn't contain enough information to be answerable vote to close as "unclear".  Some of the sub-options to off topic also apply to specific situations of missing information.

Comment: What about when the answer is within comments, and no one has answered, and it is 1yr+ old? like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688094/how-can-i-get-ghc-to-warn-about-incomplete-pattern-bindings-in-do-blocks (FWIW there are *many* of these in the haskell questions)

Comment: @JulianLeviston If the question merits closure, vote to close it, if it's a good question you want to answer it, feel free to post an answer.  If you're using a comment as a resource when posting your answer, be sure to cite it appropriately.

Comment: @Servy I pretty much just want it to go out of the "unanswered questions" list because it looks like it's never going to be answered. Is it the SO way to leave all these questions unanswered?

Comment: Like this one, for example: many votes, many answers, but none of them accepted... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525193/how-can-i-re-assign-a-variable-in-a-function-in-haskell/43526565#43526565 that means it stays in the unaswered quesitons list, when it shouldn't be there anymore.

Comment: @JulianLeviston As of right now, the question actually is unanswered.  You can either indicate that it *can't* be answered, by voting to close it, or if it's a good question, and you know the answer, you can answer it.  If the post is a good question (and so doesn't merit closure) and you don't know the answer, then the question *belongs* in the unanswered questions list, because it's an unanswered question.

Comment: @JulianLeviston For your second example, if the question merits closure, vote to close, if you know that one of the answers is the correct answer, and you're confident reccomending it to others given your expertise in the subject, then upvote one of them, if none of them are correct and you know the answer, then post your own, and if you don't know the answer or aren't qualified to evaluate the quality of the existing answers then move on to another question, because that one *belongs* in the unanswered question list.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the mechanics of stack overflow pretty well, but I'm trying to say that there's this problem where the only person who can **accept** answers is the OP, and they often have this power to ask, then easily get disinterested. Maybe this doesn't matter to SO?

Comment: @Servy as to my first example, the question has no **answers**, but there are valid answers in the comments. I notice this happens quite regularly when people want to write a quick response but it's actually an answer and that stops others from actually using the answer mechanism.

Comment: @JulianLeviston You are correct, that doesn't matter to SO.  It doesn't matter at all if the OP doesn't accept an answer.  The community is more than capable of evaluating answers all on their own, without the OP, if the OP is unable or unwilling to evaluate the quality of answers.  In fact, the community's evaluation of answers tends to be much *more* valuable than the OP's.  A question doesn't need to have an accepted answer to no longer be on the unanswered list.

Comment: @JulianLeviston And I already told you *exactly* what you can do in the situation where a question is answered in comments.  You have the tools at your disposal to do something about it, you can either choose to use them, or decide that you don't want to.  Both are perfectly acceptable options.

Comment: @Servy ok. That's not immediately obvioius (or even obvious after years of use). Thanks. FWIW, I don't like that much. It makes the unanswered/answered section kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem "just" needs some more attention. There is currently too much focus on rep-fighting over the most recent questions.

A [gold badge for revival/necromancer pattern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268) may help.

Answer (score -2):

I run into same problem, but i differ because i found my solution.
Since lately i face this more often i want add more suggestion.

in case your problem is clearly same with the question.

1. Try relative possible solution from the answer. When it work up vote.
2. Found an answer and work your case.

   - I am not really **sure** OP move on on their live.
     But the question relatively not bring attention based on asked time, view times and active time.

     ```
     nicely ask to mark an answered question
     ```
   - It's **clearly** that OP move on on their live. Also it bring big attention relatively based on **up voted** answer, asked time, and view time.

     ```
     flag the question for intervention and moderation
     ```

That my approach, let me know if it have flaw. Hope it help for the other